# Does the holographic principle imply a finite universe?

Tags: entropy, holographic-principle

Please correct me if I am wrong here, but it seems that the holographic principle sets an upper entropy bound that scales quadratically with the radius of the sphere under consideration, while the actual entropy would scale cubically (with volume)(right ?)

So, since that means that as long as entropy is non-zero almost everywhere, the actual entropy will always be able to catch up to / surpass the bound if we just make the volume under consideration large enough, does that set a bound on the size of the whole universe? Or does it mean something else? Where is the thought experiment going wrong here?

Comment: No, the whole point is that the entropy grows (at most) with the horizon area, not the volume. The problem is your assumption that the entropy depends on the volume.

Answer (score 1):

"while the actual entropy would scale cubically (with volume)(right ?)"

The Bekenstien bound that gives the entropy limit to any given volume of space is specifically starting that as you go to larger and larger scales you, the overall density of entropy must go down and down.  A really rough interpretation is that in this 3d reality there is only 2d worth of stuff. i.e. a lot of it is empty.